# R - Syuzhet Package - Possible to do sentiment analysis by sentences and not by words?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I've done two separate sentiment analyses using **sentiment package** and **syuzhet package**.

My understanding is that `classify_emotion()` from the sentiment package can classify **sentences** into different emotions, however `get_nrc_sentiment()` from the syuzhet package classify **words** in sentences.

For instance, I'm using 4,000 sentences (Twitter feeds) for my sentiment analyses: sentiment package produces 4,000 rows and syuzhet packages produces >4,000 rows.

Is there any way to classify sentences (not words) into different emotion using the syuzhet package like sentiment package does?

Comment: You didn't have 4000 sentences. You had 4000 rows and some had extra sentences.  Also to get what you got I think you used `get_sentences`: `x <- c("I love it.  It's awesome!", 'yes indeed.', 'very bad alrighty then.'); syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(x); syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(syuzhet::get_sentences(x))`  Stop using that and it should give 4000 rows back.

Comment: You can use the function qdap::polarity() to extract polarity score as average polarity.

Comment: Maybe this is a good idea: get the sentiment for each word using Syuzhet, sum them up for each sentence, then use summary sentiment statistics for the sentence (mean, max, min, standard deviation)